# Unity Tcp /Ip Microphone Audio along Video Streaming

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcpclient, microphone

I'm new to unity.

I'm trying to stream audio from the microphone with a live video from one app to the another, Currently, I have 2 apps. were app 1 is the server/sender and app 2 is the client/receiver. In-app 1 I successfully send the video bytes to the client. and on the client side, I'm also receiving all of the bytes. I'm using sockets and TCP.

Now the problem is I don't know how to send microphone's audio along with video from the server to the client.

Below code works perfectly for live video streaming from server side

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Connecting : MonoBehaviour
{
    WebCamTexture webCam;
    public RawImage myImage;
    public bool enableLog = false;

    Texture2D currentTexture;

    private TcpListener listner;
    private const int port = 8010;
    private bool stop = false;

    private List<TcpClient> clients = new List<TcpClient>();

    //This must be the-same with SEND_COUNT on the client
    const int SEND_RECEIVE_COUNT = 15;

    private void Start()
    {
        Application.runInBackground = true;

        //Start WebCam coroutine
        StartCoroutine(initAndWaitForWebCamTexture());
    }


    //Converts the data size to byte array and put result to the fullBytes array
    void byteLengthToFrameByteArray(int byteLength, byte[] fullBytes)
    {
        //Clear old data
        Array.Clear(fullBytes, 0, fullBytes.Length);
        //Convert int to bytes
        byte[] bytesToSendCount = BitConverter.GetBytes(byteLength);
        //Copy result to fullBytes
        bytesToSendCount.CopyTo(fullBytes, 0);
    }

    //Converts the byte array to the data size and returns the result
    int frameByteArrayToByteLength(byte[] frameBytesLength)
    {
        int byteLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(frameBytesLength, 0);
        return byteLength;
    }

    IEnumerator initAndWaitForWebCamTexture()
    {
        // Open the Camera on the desired device, in my case IPAD pro
        webCam = new WebCamTexture();
        // Get all devices , front and back camera
        webCam.deviceName = WebCamTexture.devices[WebCamTexture.devices.Length - 1].name;

        // request the lowest width and heigh possible
        webCam.requestedHeight = 10;
        webCam.requestedWidth = 10;

        myImage.texture = webCam;

        webCam.Play();

        currentTexture = new Texture2D(webCam.width, webCam.height);

        // Connect to the server
        listner = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);

        listner.Start();

        while (webCam.width < 100)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        //Start sending coroutine
        StartCoroutine(senderCOR());
    }

    WaitForEndOfFrame endOfFrame = new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    IEnumerator senderCOR()
    {

        bool isConnected = false;
        TcpClient client = null;
        NetworkStream stream = null;

        // Wait for client to connect in another Thread 
        Loom.RunAsync(() =>
        {
            while (!stop)
            {
                // Wait for client connection
                client = listner.AcceptTcpClient();
                // We are connected
                clients.Add(client);

                isConnected = true;
                stream = client.GetStream();
            }
        });

        //Wait until client has connected
        while (!isConnected)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        LOG("Connected!");

        bool readyToGetFrame = true;

        byte[] frameBytesLength = new byte[SEND_RECEIVE_COUNT];

        while (!stop)
        {
            //Wait for End of frame
            yield return endOfFrame;

            currentTexture.SetPixels(webCam.GetPixels());
            byte[] pngBytes = currentTexture.EncodeToPNG();
            //Fill total byte length to send. Result is stored in frameBytesLength
            byteLengthToFrameByteArray(pngBytes.Length, frameBytesLength);

            //Set readyToGetFrame false
            readyToGetFrame = false;

            Loom.RunAsync(() =>
            {
                //Send total byte count first
                stream.Write(frameBytesLength, 0, frameBytesLength.Length);
                LOG("Sent Image byte Length: " + frameBytesLength.Length);

                //Send the image bytes
                stream.Write(pngBytes, 0, pngBytes.Length);
                LOG("Sending Image byte array data : " + pngBytes.Length);

                //Sent. Set readyToGetFrame true
                readyToGetFrame = true;
            });

            //Wait until we are ready to get new frame(Until we are done sending data)
            while (!readyToGetFrame)
            {
                LOG("Waiting To get new frame");
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }


    void LOG(string messsage)
    {
        if (enableLog)
            Debug.Log(messsage);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        myImage.texture = webCam;
    }

    // stop everything
    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        if (webCam != null && webCam.isPlaying)
        {
            webCam.Stop();
            stop = true;
        }

        if (listner != null)
        {
            listner.Stop();
        }

        foreach (TcpClient c in clients)
            c.Close();
    }
}
```

Below code works perfect for live video streaming from Client side

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class reciver : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RawImage image;
    public bool enableLog = false;

    const int port = 8010;
    public string IP = "192.168.1.165";
    TcpClient client;

    Texture2D tex;

    private bool stop = false;

    //This must be the-same with SEND_COUNT on the server
    const int SEND_RECEIVE_COUNT = 15;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Application.runInBackground = true;

        tex = new Texture2D(0, 0);
        client = new TcpClient();

        //Connect to server from another Thread
        Loom.RunAsync(() =>
        {
            LOGWARNING("Connecting to server...");
            // if on desktop
            client.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, port);

            // if using the IPAD
            //client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
            LOGWARNING("Connected!");

            imageReceiver();
        });
    }


    void imageReceiver()
    {
        //While loop in another Thread is fine so we don't block main Unity Thread
        Loom.RunAsync(() =>
        {
            while (!stop)
            {
                //Read Image Count
                int imageSize = readImageByteSize(SEND_RECEIVE_COUNT);
                LOGWARNING("Received Image byte Length: " + imageSize);

                //Read Image Bytes and Display it
                readFrameByteArray(imageSize);
            }
        });
    }


    //Converts the data size to byte array and put result to the fullBytes array
    void byteLengthToFrameByteArray(int byteLength, byte[] fullBytes)
    {
        //Clear old data
        Array.Clear(fullBytes, 0, fullBytes.Length);
        //Convert int to bytes
        byte[] bytesToSendCount = BitConverter.GetBytes(byteLength);
        //Copy result to fullBytes
        bytesToSendCount.CopyTo(fullBytes, 0);
    }

    //Converts the byte array to the data size and returns the result
    int frameByteArrayToByteLength(byte[] frameBytesLength)
    {
        int byteLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(frameBytesLength, 0);
        return byteLength;
    }


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////Read Image SIZE from Server///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private int readImageByteSize(int size)
    {
        bool disconnected = false;

        NetworkStream serverStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] imageBytesCount = new byte[size];
        var total = 0;
        do
        {
            var read = serverStream.Read(imageBytesCount, total, size - total);
            //Debug.LogFormat("Client recieved {0} bytes", total);
            if (read == 0)
            {
                disconnected = true;
                break;
            }
            total += read;
        } while (total != size);

        int byteLength;

        if (disconnected)
        {
            byteLength = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            byteLength = frameByteArrayToByteLength(imageBytesCount);
        }
        return byteLength;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////Read Image Data Byte Array from Server///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void readFrameByteArray(int size)
    {
        bool disconnected = false;

        NetworkStream serverStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] imageBytes = new byte[size];
        var total = 0;
        do
        {
            var read = serverStream.Read(imageBytes, total, size - total);
            //Debug.LogFormat("Client recieved {0} bytes", total);
            if (read == 0)
            {
                disconnected = true;
                break;
            }
            total += read;
        } while (total != size);

        bool readyToReadAgain = false;

        //Display Image
        if (!disconnected)
        {
            //Display Image on the main Thread
            Loom.QueueOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                displayReceivedImage(imageBytes);
                readyToReadAgain = true;
            });
        }

        //Wait until old Image is displayed
        while (!readyToReadAgain)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }


    void displayReceivedImage(byte[] receivedImageBytes)
    {
        tex.LoadImage(receivedImageBytes);
        image.texture = tex;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


    }


    void LOG(string messsage)
    {
        if (enableLog)
            Debug.Log(messsage);
    }

    void LOGWARNING(string messsage)
    {
        if (enableLog)
            Debug.LogWarning(messsage);
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        LOGWARNING("OnApplicationQuit");
        stop = true;

        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

My Achievement for video so far is below, in below code audio is successfully playing from microphone

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class Audio1 : MonoBehaviour
 {
     const int FREQUENCY = 44100;
     AudioClip mic;
     int lastPos, pos;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start()
     {
         mic = Microphone.Start(null, true, 10, FREQUENCY);

         AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
         audio.clip = AudioClip.Create("test", 10 * FREQUENCY, mic.channels, FREQUENCY, false);
         audio.loop = true;

     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         if ((pos = Microphone.GetPosition(null)) > 0)
         {
             if (lastPos > pos) lastPos = 0;

             if (pos - lastPos > 0)
             {
                 // Allocate the space for the sample.
                 float[] sample = new float[(pos - lastPos) * mic.channels];

                 // Get the data from microphone.
                 mic.GetData(sample, lastPos);

                 // Put the data in the audio source.
                 AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
                 audio.clip.SetData(sample, lastPos);

                 if (!audio.isPlaying) audio.Play();

                 lastPos = pos;
             }
         }
     }

     void OnDestroy()
     {
         Microphone.End(null);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Have you found any solution for streaming audio ?

Comment: @chetanrane not yet

Comment: @chetanrane plz help me if you find solution